# Selecting all duplicates from table

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I'v got a table with columns like this:

```
serial_id   season  ep_id
1           1       1   < duplicate
1           1       2
3           1       1
...
1           1       1   < duplicate
```

I want to select all rows that have a duplicated values in serial_id, season and ep_id , what query i should use?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**"..duplicated values in serial_id, season and ep_id."**

```
SELECT  serial_id, ep_id, season
FROM    tableName
GROUP   BY serial_id, ep_id, season
HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e20a5/5)

but if you want to get all columns (*assuming you have other columns except serial_id, ep_id, season*) within the row

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  serial_id, ep_id, season
            FROM    tableName
            GROUP   BY serial_id, ep_id, season
            HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1
        ) b ON  a.serial_id = b.serial_id AND
                a.ep_id = b.ep_id AND
                a.season = b.season
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e20a5/8)

Answer (score 1):

something like this:

```
select serial_id, season, ep_id, count(*) records
from yourtable
group by serial_id, season, ep_id
having count(*) > 1
```